# Generating a Pdf for all the android code documentation

Tags: android, javadoc

I have a big android code. I wish to generate a PDF containing all class summaries and comments. Can anyone suggest me a proper way of doing that..Searched stack overflow for this but couldn't find a proper way.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: i dont know if this helps but try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322048/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-javadoc-including-overview-and-package-summaries

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate Javdoc

- For this select Project---->Generate Javadoc

[image]

- Choose Configure & provide the path of Javadoc.exe (You will get it by command **`where javadoc.exe`**)
- Choose the project , output directory and proceed.